# Get _id of an inserted document in MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

say I have a product listing. When I add a new product I save it using something like

```
var doc=products.Insert<ProductPDO>(p);
```

The problem is that I want after this is done to redirect the user to the page with the product. So I need to redirect to say `/products/<ObjectID>`

However, I see no way of getting the ObjectID right afterwards without manually querying the database and look for a document with all the same fields and such.

Is there an easier way? (also, `doc` in this instance returns null for some reason)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The `Insert` method automatically sets the property that is declared as the BSON ID of the model.

If declared as follows...

```
[BsonId]
public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
```

... then the `Id` field will contain the default (new, unique) BSON ID of the object after inserting the object into a collection:

```
coll.Insert(obj);
// obj.Id is now the BSON ID of the object
```

Comment: for those newer to .NET this is still not clear. In what c sharp object can I extract the new ID? can you post example code?

Comment: You can extract the ObjectId (Id) from the class object that was inserted.

Comment: This only works for insertOne? I doesn't seem to do it for insertMany...

Comment: @mr_T I was using `InsertManyAsync` in C# and was also seeing that IDs were not populated in the C# objects after the call. I was passing in the result of a LINQ `Select` (`IEnumerable<>`), but switched to passing in a `List<>` and now the IDs are populated. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42605122/c-sharp-mongodb-insertmany-missing-id-after-insert .

Answer (score 20):

When you insert an object into the mongodb, mongo will update the object with the internal ID.

So if

```
data = {
  title: "Howdy"
}
```

Then when we insert the data object into the db

```
db.collection('collectionName', function(err, collection) {
  collection.insert(data);
  console.log(data._id); // <- The mongodb id is now set on the item
});
```

Answer (score 6):

As the comment above, add the fild ID in your model with

```
[BsonId]
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
public string id { get; set; }
```

using:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
```

and then when you insert the object, mongo return the ID of the document into the fild ID of the model.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the type of ID you can do something like this:

```
public static TId GetId<TId>(this BsonDocument document) where TId : struct
{
    if (document == default(BsonDocument))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("document");
    }

    var id = document["_id"];

    object idAsObject;

    if (id.IsGuid)
    {
        idAsObject = (object)id.AsGuid;
    }
    else if (id.IsObjectId)
    {
        idAsObject = (object)id.AsObjectId;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(string.Format("Unknown _id type \"{0}\"", id.BsonType));
    }

    var idCasted = (TId)idAsObject;

    return idCasted;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Guid idOfDoc = myBsonDocument.GetId<Guid>();
```

Still you should prefere have a dedicated property as in the chosen answer...

Answer (score 2):

I'm converting the custom type `T` to `BsonDocument` before persisting it.

```
var bsonDocument = item.ToBsonDocument();
_mongoCollection.InsertOne(bsonDocument);
```

`T` has a property Id:

```
[BsonId]
public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
```

When I call `ToBsonDocument()`, the `Id` field gets populated with `ObjectId` which gets pushed to Mongo DB.

It creates the Id itself in the code instead of delegating to Mongo DB to create it. But it suffices my case.

Answer (score 1):

```
class BsonID
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
}
var document = new BsonDocument {
   {"_id", new BsonID().Id },
   { "code", dr.Cells["code"].Value.ToString() },
   { "name", dr.Cells["name"].Value.ToString() },
  };
var customers = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Customers");
customers.InsertOne(document);
var id = document.ElementAt(0).Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

2021: If you are using MongoDb with a C#9 `record`s, you can use this hack to get an inserted id:

```cs
private async Task<T> AddEntity<T>(T entity, string collectionName) where T: EntityBase
{
    var col = _db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName);
    var document = entity.ToBsonDocument();
    document["_id"] = ObjectId.Empty;
    await col.InsertOneAsync(document);
    var insertedEntity = entity with
    {
        id = document["_id"].ToString()!
    };
    return insertedEntity;
}
```

Where `EntityBase` your base entity for all documents that has `id` field. Or just don't use generics.

Answer (score 0):

Class.Type as a BsonDocument not the real Class.Type can be a common cause for this issue:

e.g.:

```
var stream = mDB.GetCollection<vStreamMessage>(dictINI[sMONGODB_COLLECTION_NAME]);
            stream.InsertOne(msg);
```

Not

```
var stream = mDB.GetCollection<**BsonDocument**>(dictINI[sMONGODB_COLLECTION_NAME]);
            stream.InsertOne(**msg.ToBsonDocument**);
```