# C# MongoDB InsertMany missing _id after insert

Tags: c#, mongodb

So I have two functions as follows. The InsertOne() function works fine, and the BsonDocument is updated with the newly created _id. However, the InsertMany() function is not returning object ids. I debugged the code, and none of the individual documents are updated with an _id field.

The InsertMany() function does insert the documents into the database, and I can see they all have object ids from the Mongo shell.

The models in my code do not have an Id field. And they are being converted using code like MyModel.ToBsonDocument().

Am I missing something to get back the IDs generated from a bulk insert?

```
    public string InsertOne(BsonDocument document)
    {
        MongoCollection.InsertOne(document);
        return document["_id"].ToString();
    }

    public string[] InsertMany(IEnumerable<BsonDocument> documents)
    {
        MongoCollection.InsertMany(documents);
        return documents.Select(item => Convert.ToString(item["_id"])).ToArray();
    }
```

**EDIT** - Not sure if this is a bug, but I just realized if I use a list instead of IEnumerable, the InsertMany() works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with how collections are created our of `IEnumerable` in LINQ. `MongoCollection.InsertMany` materializes the collection under the hood by enumerating over it and populating `_id`. However it's a new collection and it's not the `IEnumerable` that you initially passed in, that's why it doesn't have the ids. If you pass `List` the collection has already been materialized, so it just populates the fields in it.