# Get _id of an inserted document in MongoDB when using BsonClassMap?

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

Before anyone marks this question as a duplicate of [Get _id of an inserted document in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4582912/9522887) please read the whole question.

I am developing a ASP.NET Core API app with MongoDB driver.

**The problem I am facing is that after inserting a document in the database the `Id` property of the `Post` class is not assigned the id generated by MongoDB.**

I found few questions where they solved it using the annotations/attributes in the class but, I am developing a pattern where domain classes don't have any persistence knowledge.

I have created the entity class without annotations:

```
public class Post
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

And defined mapping using `BsonClassMap`:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Domain.Entities.Post>(x =>
        {
            x.AutoMap();
            x.MapIdField(x => x.Id)
                .SetSerializer(new StringSerializer(BsonType.ObjectId))
                .SetIgnoreIfDefault(true);
        });
```

Here's is the code:

```
public async Task Create(Domain.Entities.Post entity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        async Task Create()
        {
            await Post.InsertOneAsync(entity);
        }
        await Create();
        var e = entity;
    }
```

When I inspect the entity the Id property is null.

**So, how do I get id when using the `BsonClassMap`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, your code knows how to read Ids when they come as `ObjectId` from the database but still needs help when it comes to generating ids on the client side,

The missing part is `SetIdGenerator` method invocation, try:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Post>(x =>
    {
        x.AutoMap();
        x.MapIdField(x => x.Id)
            .SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance)
            .SetSerializer(new StringSerializer(BsonType.ObjectId))
            .SetIgnoreIfDefault(true);
    });
```

Now ObjectIds will be generated and turned into string on the client side so you should be able to see them when you hover over `e` variable.

Details [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.12/reference/bson/mapping/#id-generators).

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get the id after setting the Generator. But, I had seen it being done without setting the Generator. I could not figure out how they have done it though.